# Acumatica Content Pack does not get loaded

Tags: acumatica

The Acmatica Link https:// works with UserID and Password Given with Basic Authentication.

Howerver, the Acumatica Content Pack does not get loaded in the PowerBI Site.
The screen shows just loading ??

Is there any Demo Site where Acumatica Content Pack is displayed ??.

Comment: I got the SSL on the site first and finally could get the Acumatica Content Pack visible in powerbi.microsoft.com. Odata queries had to be done to all the generic queries !